# NSFetchedResultsController didChangeObject method called when entity saving failed

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an Master/Detail app with Core Data. I'm newbie about Core Data so I don't understand why when I add a new entity and `context.save(&error)` return `false` (for example because I don't set a non optional attribute) the `func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?)` method is called though the object is not saved.

Anyone can help me to understand?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using NSFetchedResultsController **ALL** changes to the context you're using are being sent to the NSFetchedResultsController. The NSFetchedResultsController listens to the context, **not the store**.

The data is only persisted to the database (an example of a persistentStore) when you call the save method. However when the save method is called, the context updates. I figured this out too when my UITableView was getting slow because the NSFetchedResultsController was updating my cells twice. **First you add the object the the context, but when you save, it updates the context again.**

What I did to remedy this is implementing a second context for background operations and only when i persist the changes in the background context, i send them to the foreground, making it so that my UI only updates once.

Perhaps you could check out the following link to see if you'd need a similar solution. This link showed me most clearly what happened and what I needed.

- http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/

Comment: When the Optional property comes into play? If I have a User entity with a mandatory property name, why, in the context, is accepted a User without name? Thanks. You addressed me in the right direction.

Comment: Is it correct to assert that context.save(&error) can fail only for a programmer bug? If so, I'm not worried about it.

Comment: I'm making assumptions here, but I think they can't enforce the optional checks onto the NSManagedObject classes. That's why they don't tell you the object is invalid when it is saved to the context. However when you try to persist them to the database, the store checks if your object is valid. They probably had a few other reasons to implement the context as you currently use it, but I wouldn't know of them. I think you will be forced to write your own checks or maybe use a custom init method(I don't know what the super requires so it may be impossible) that checks your required values.